# pandas: get column and row name where row has the highest value for every row

Tags: python, pandas, filter, max

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'sent':['one','two','three'], 'val_1':[2,4,8], 'val_2': [4,7,1], 'val_3':[9,3,6]})
```

I would like to get the rows that have the highest value along with the column name they appear in and the sent number as a list of dict, e.g my desired output is,

```
output = [{'sent': 'one', 'val_3': 9}, {'sent': 'two', 'val_2': 7}, {'sent': 'three', 'val_1': 8}]
```

i have tried the following:

```
dict = data.to_dict('records')
for i in dict:
   for k,v in i.items():
          if not isinstance(v, str):
                 print(i, key =i.get) # sends an error
```

I also tried to filter the max value but cannot get the column name to proceed.

```
data[['val_1','val_2','val_3']].max()
```

Comment: I think you must use something like `col_name` in order to store the column name, and/or store the higher value. In the format you are trying to achieve it will try to create new column with `val_x` or will directly fail because of that.

Comment: `where row has the highest value for every row`, it sounds strange. are you looking for max value per col or per row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set 'sent' as index and use a list comprehension:

```
df = data.set_index('sent')
output = [{'sent': k, v: df.loc[k,v]} for k,v in df.idxmax(1).iteritems()]
```

output:

```
[{'sent': 'one', 'val_3': 9},
 {'sent': 'two', 'val_2': 7},
 {'sent': 'three', 'val_1': 8}]
```